# saving python object in postgres table with pickle

Tags: python, postgresql, pickle

I have a python script which creates some objects. 
I would like to be able to save these objects into my postgres database for use later.

My thinking was I could pickle an object, then store that in a field in the db. 
But I'm going round in circles about how to store and retrieve and use the data.

I've tried storing the pickle binary string as  `text` but I can't work out how to  encode / escape it. Then how to load the string as a binary string to unpickle.

I've tried storing the data as `bytea` both with `psycopg2.Binary(data)` and without.
Then reading into buffer and encoding with `base64.b64encode(result)` but it's not coming out the same and cannot be unpickled.

Is there a simple way to store and retrieve python objects in a SQL (postgres) database?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the `base64` functions in the right order? Just to check, what you want is: Storing `object` `->` `pickle` `->` `base64-encode` `->` `DB`. Reading back: `DB` `->` `base64-decode` `->` `unpickle` `->` `object`.

Comment: I think this answer would help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469575/how-to-pickle-and-unpickle-to-portable-string-in-python-3

Comment: @SergioPulgarin I wasn't encoding before sending to the database. If I do that, should I store it as text or binary in the db?

Answer (score 8):

Following the comment from @SergioPulgarin I tried the following which worked!

*N.B Edit2 following comment by @Tomalak*

**Storing:**

1. Pickle the object to a binary string

   `pickle_string = pickle.dumps(object)`
2. Store the pickle string in a bytea (binary) field in postgres. Use simple `INSERT` query in Psycopg2

**Retrieval:**

1. `Select` the field in Psycopg2. (simple `SELECT` query)
2. Unpickle the decoded result

   `retrieved_pickle_string = pickle.loads(decoded_result)`

Hope that helps anybody trying to do something similar!

Comment: The "encode as base64" step is superfluous here. You can store the pickled object directly in a binary field.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for pointing that out, I removed that step and it also works great!