# Storing a pickled dictionary in Postgresql (Psycopg2)

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, pickle

I am trying to store a pickled nested dictionary in Postgresql (I am aware that this is a quick & dirty method and won't be able to access dictionary contents from Postgresql - usually bad practice)

```
# boilerplate, preamble and upstream work.
import psycopg2


''' Inputs: nd = dictionary to be pickled '''



pickled = pickle.dumps(nd)

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "-----",
                              password = "----",
                              host = "----",
                              port = "----",
                              database = "----")
    
name = 'database1'    
    
    
print('Connected...')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print(connection.get_dsn_parameters(),"\n")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE thetable (name TEXT, ablob BYTEA)")
print('Created Table...')
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(%s)",(psycopg2.Binary(pickled),))
connection.commit()
print('Added Data...')
cursor.close()
connection.close()
print('Connection closed...')
```

When I come to data data retrieval, I am having many issues importing the data from Postgres - essentially the data is to be opened, unpickled back to the dictionary and visualised. I have tried:

```
import psycopg2
from io import BytesIO

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "----",
                              password = "----",
                              host = "----",
                              port = "----",
                              database = "----")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT ablob FROM thetable")
result, = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
connection.rollback()

result = BytesIO(result)

print(pickle.load(result))
```

As per this link: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch08s08.html, and consulted: [Insert an image in postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288898/insert-an-image-in-postgresql-database/46314519?noredirect=1#comment93152073_46314519) and: [saving python object in postgres table with pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642165/saving-python-object-in-postgres-table-with-pickle), however have been unable to return the pickled dictionary.

Any advice in achieving this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your code runs without throwing an exception?  Your insert should look like:  `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(%s, %s)",('some name', psycopg2.Binary(pickled),))`  Also, I never heard of the `psycopg2.Binary()` wrapper.  I just pass the `b''` object.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions, and when I checked the Heroku Postgres database, 'abloom' and 'name' are both present within the table (although unsure if populated)

Comment: @Mike Organek. Per the docs [Binary](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html?highlight=binary#psycopg2.Binary).

Comment: I would check to see if there is data in the table.  I'm with @Mike Organek, I don't see how ```"INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(%s)",(psycopg2.Binary(pickled),)``` can succeed. You either need to change to ```"INSERT INTO thetable(ablob) VALUES(%s)",(psycopg2.Binary(pickled),)``` or to what Mike suggested.

Comment: Update to my previous comment. Because you did not specify columns and only supplied one value, that value would be inserted into ```name``` as ```INSERT``` matches columns in their declared order in a 1:1 to the ```VALUES``` supplied.  As long as the string to be inserted does not run afoul of character rules it would succeed. The ```ablob``` in this case would be set to ```NULL```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `CREATE TABLE` lists two fields, you have to  list in INSERT which ones you want to fill, unless you fill them all.

```
import psycopg2
import pickle

dict = {
  "foo": "bar"
}

p = pickle.dumps(dict)

connection = psycopg2.connect(database = "test")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE thetable (name TEXT, ablob BYTEA)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO thetable VALUES(%s,%s)",('test',p))
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

and reading

```
import psycopg2
import pickle

connection = psycopg2.connect(database = "test")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT ablob FROM thetable WHERE name='test';")
result = cursor.fetchone()

print pickle.loads(result[0])

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```