# dump and load pickled object to sql database

Tags: python, persistence, pickle, rdbms

I want to store an `xgboost` model to an sql database and read it back:

1. I pickled my model and wrote it into a varchar field in my db:

   `obj = pickle.dumps(mymodel)`  #write obj to db in a varchar field
2. When I read the string back from the database into obj and want to `pickle.loads(obj[0])`, I get this error:

   `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not a 'str'`

How can I unpickle the string (obj) from my database?

Comment: This isn't really a <sql> language related question. But you could add tag tag for the dbms instead.

Comment: Most varchar column types are going to expect characters (with a particular character encoding).  A pickle produces a binary type-- so database-wise you'd probably want to store that in a blob type field.  If you really want to use a character based field, you'll probably want to base64 encode your pickled object before putting in the database and then base64 decode when retrieving it (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469575/how-to-pickle-and-unpickle-to-portable-string-in-python-3)